# Animated GIF as an icon for notification

Tags: java, android, gif, android-notifications

Is it possible to set an animated GIF as an icon for Notification? I know that I can split it into a set of static images and then use animation-list but splitting is a hard work for complex animation.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to set an animated GIF as an icon for Notification?

Yes. However, it will not animate.

Comment: it does in latest android istnt? or we need to "I know that I can split it into a set of static images and then use animation-list but splitting is a hard work for complex animation" I see download icon animating..

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder: If you mean the platform's download icon, that's an `AnimationDrawable` (`animation-list` resource).